# Derivative with respect to the initial datum of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose I have a stochastic differential equation of the form
$$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dW_t \quad X_0=x_0 \in \mathbb R^n.$$
My professor said that in some cases one wants to compute the derivative of $X_t$ with respect to the initial datum $\frac{\partial X_t}{  \partial x_0 }.$

Where can I find a reference for this?

Comment: Cases like? Applications?

Comment: He didn’t specify and in fact I was curious also about this

Comment: I recently encountered a similar problem, as I would like to find an approximation of $X_t$ starting at $X_0 = x$ knowing $X_t$ starting at $X_0=0$, like a Taylor expansion of the stochastic process. don't know if any references exist on the subject

Comment: Well, for small t you can use such result with Taylor of course. For big t I dont know what can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kunita's lectures cover this eg. [Lectures on
Stochastic Flows And Applications](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/%7Epubl/ln/tifr78.pdf), i.e. depending on the regularity of the coefficients we have analogous differentiability in initial conditions

[image]

Another source is in Varadhan's notes too [Stochastic1](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/fall06/Stochastic1.pdf)

[image]

The proof goes through creating new systems satisfied by the derivative processes and then showing existence-uniqueness for the entire system.